# How do you create a numpy vertical arange?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>> print np.array([np.arange(10)]).transpose()

[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]
 [8]
 [9]]
```

Is there a way to get a vertical arange without having to go through these extra steps?

Comment: You're already doing some unnecessary steps there - the `np.array()` and the `[]` are unnecessary since `np.arange` returns a numpy array.  You can just do `np.arange(10).transpose()`

Comment: @Brionius, `transpose` of a 1d array doesn't do anything. The OP is using the `[]` to add an extra dimension to the array and is asking if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @BiRico Ah, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: "You're already doing some unnecessary steps there" -- I figured, that's why I asked.

Comment: @BiRico is there a different way to add a dimension to the array? For some reason my `np.array` is not actually working...idk why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [np.newaxis](http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#newaxis):

```
>>> np.arange(10)[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

`np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None`, and was added by `numpy` developers mainly for readability. Therefore `np.arange(10)[:, None]` would produce the same exact result as the above solution.

**Edit:**

Another option is:

```
np.expand_dims(np.arange(10), axis=1)
```

[numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: @JasonS, I added a link with an example.

Comment: @JasonS - Have a look at: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing  The docs are rather consice, so see one of the guides or books (as Akavall linked to) for more examples.

Comment: @JasonS I don't know either... I [just posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18163958/832621) for that...

Comment: @SaulloCastro, good question, so I guess `np.newaxis` was introduced just because it is easier to read.

Answer (score 14):

I would do:

```
np.arange(10).reshape((10, 1))
```

Unlike np.array, reshape is a light weight operation which does not copy the data in the array.

Comment: On a side note, you can also do `whatever.reshape(-1, 1)`, to avoid having to specify the size of the first dimension.