# Why "None" has the same effect as "np.newaxis"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nonetype

Why `None` has the save effect of `np.newaxis`? For example, using:

```
np.arange(10)[:,None]
```

or:

```
np.arange(10)[:,np.newaxis]
```

both create:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Does anyone know the reason for `np.newaxis==None`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thats because [`numpy.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) is an alias for `None` as it says in the documentation: *`None` can also be used instead of `newaxis`.*

Comment: It's simply because `newaxis` is more explicit about what it would do, intsead of `None`

Answer (score 3):

Look here:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.newaxis)
None
>>>
```

`numpy.newaxis` *is* `None`.